# List index out of range, splitting regular expression match

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

For some reason this little part of my code is giving me a problem. I have been trying to figure out why it is giving me a "list index out of range" error

```
#This works fine, and finds a match
if re.search("Manufacturer\/Distributor name:?", arg) != None:

    #---->This is giving me the problem, "List index out of range"<----
    address = arg.split("Manufacturer\/Distributor name:?", 1)[1]
```

This is the arg I'm feeding it:

> Product Name: Tio Nacho Shampoo Mexican Herbs Recommended Use: Shampoo **Manufacturer/Distributor name:** Garcoa Laboratories, Inc. 26135 Mureau Road Calabasas, CA 91302 (818) 225 - 0375 Emerg ency telephone number: CHEMTREC 1 - 800 - 424 - 9300 2 .

When I have it set to [1], this is the result:

```
List index out of range
```

When I have the split set to [0], this is the result:

```
/Distributor name: Garcoa Laboratories, Inc. 26135 Mureau Road Calabasas, CA 91302 (818) 225 - 0375 Emerg ency telephone number: CHEMTREC 1 - 800 - 424 - 9300 2 .
```

I'm trying to get this result:

```
Garcoa Laboratories, Inc. 26135 Mureau Road Calabasas, CA 91302 (818) 225 - 0375 Emerg ency telephone number: CHEMTREC 1 - 800 - 424 - 9300 2 .
```

Its matching to it, but the split for some reason doesn't want to work. What am I missing? Why does it give that result for [0]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The argument to `split()` is not a regular expression, it's just a plain string. So it's not splitting because there's no `?` in the input string.

Comment: Also, you need to escape the backslash `\ `. Oh and to use regex, use `re.search()` instead of the `split()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.split()` doesn't take a regular expression, you need to use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split).

```
address = re.split(r'Manufacturer\/Distributor name:?', arg, 1)[1]
```

You should also get in the habit of using raw strings for regular expressions, otherwise you need to escape the `\`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming `arg` is a string. `string.split()` does not accept regex as delimiter. You can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Instead, you should use `arg.split("Manufacturer/Distributor name", 1)[1]`.

Comment: But apparently the `:` is optional, so it might not be there.

Comment: @Barmar By following the regex, yes, you're correct. Code fixed.

Comment: Now it will include the `:` in the result.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, your answer is more accurate :)